# Can I Initialize a derived class reference with a base class reference to derived class instance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, reference, dynamic-cast, downcast

I have something like the following:

```
class A { ... };
class B : public A { ... };

// ...

B b;
const A& aref(b);

// ...

const B& bref(aref);
```

and when I compile, I get:

```
no suitable user-defined conversion from "const A" to "const B" exists
```

Now, if these were pointers rather than references, I would use

```
bptr = dynamic_cast<B*>(aptr);
```

but references don't have that. What should I do? Switch to pointers? something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `dynamic_cast` for references, they just throw an exception rather than returning `nullptr` on failure:

```
try {
    const B& bref(dynamic_cast<const B&>(aref));
}
catch (const std::bad_cast& e) {
    //handle error
}
```

If you *absolutely know* that `aref` is actually a `B`, then you can do a `static_cast`:

```
const B& bref(static_cast<const B&>(aref));
```